# How to cut part from log file?

Tags: text-processing, logs

I have an 8 Gb log file (Rails production log).  I need to cut it between some dates (lines).  Which command could I use to do this?

Comment: Hey guys, this question is about a **big** file, so it's "Ante up!".. time matters...I've tested the favoured sed script on a real 8 GB file, with 85904064 lines (100 chars per line). I love sed, but as it stands, the sed script scans the entire file, **every** time. This makes it on average twice as slow as the awk script which exits-when-found... I think(?) the sed script **may** just need a q instead of d for the second expression... The test results are here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/573477/ .. Also, it doesn't produce the proper output.. see my comment at the end asoundmove's answer.

Comment: asoundmove's new sed version had addressed the speed issue, and it now matches awks's speed. and the new versin now outputs data correctly... see his comments for more detail.

Comment: I just noticed you said "cut" (which typically means remove)... Do you really mean "cut", or do you mean "copy"? .... If you did mean "cut", then `sed` will do it easily.

Answer (score 12):

Something like

```
sed '1,/last date prior to chunk/d;/first date after chunk/,$d' logfile | tee cut-log | less
```

`tee cut-log` allows you to see on screen what is being put in file `cut-log`.

EDIT:

To satisfy fred.bear's exacting standards, here's a sed solution (though arguably the awk solution is a lot prettier):

```
b=BB; e=EE ;echo -e "AA\nAA\nBB\nBB\nCC\nCC\nDD\nDD\nEE\nEE\nFF\nFF" | sed -n ":b;/$b/b p;n;b b;:p;p;n;/$e/b e;b p;:e;p;n;/$e/b e;q"
```

Comment: -1 UUOC http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html

Comment: @dogbane: yeah, yeah. Edited. I'm sure you sometimes write less than optimal code, does it deserve such a harsh comment?

Comment: "I need to cut part *between* some dates"... That sounds like just what you've done with the "delete" method ... It took me a few moments to understand why you chose the "delete" method..(until I checked the question)... and the `tee` is a nice touch.

Comment: note: If there are multiple consecutive 'first-date' lines with the same date, all but the first will *not* be deleted, and will be introduced to the output... just something to be aware of... (it depends on the  situation)

Comment: @fred: I though of writing `/first date in chunk/-1` but this does not work, though it would be great if it did, hence me pointing to `/last date prior to chunk/` and `/first date after chunk/` - this will work. dogbane's method is just as good, but needs more explaining: FOO needs to be the first date in chunk, BAR needs to be the last date in the chunk (inclusive).

Comment: another note... Big problems if either of the dates aren't present in the data!

Comment: People who care about useless use of cat are small in number but strong in convinction. It's like the UL equivalent of people who flip out when you call it the "ternary operator" on SO

Comment: @asoundmove; your script only removes the FIRST line matching your first search expression: What about repeating dates? Here is a TEST example: EXPECTED output is CC CC DD DD, but it produces BB CC CC DD DD ... $ b=BB; e=EE ;echo -e "AA\nAA\nBB\nBB\nCC\nCC\nDD\nDD\nEE\nEE\nFF\nFF" >logfile ; sed '1,/'$b'/d;/'$e'/,$d' logfile

Comment: @asoundmove: This `q` mod will solve your speed issue, but it does introduce a blank line at the end. I've never worked with `q` before today.. I'm sure there is a cleaner way... but you will need introduce a sub-loop into your logic to cater for the extra leading records... Here is the `q` version:  `b=BB; e=EE ;echo -e "AA\nAA\nBB\nBB\nCC\nCC\nDD\nDD\nEE\nEE\nFF\nFF" | sed '1,/'$b'/d;/'$e'/{g;q}' ....(but until you add some sub logic, it will keep printing unwanted "exclude-this" arg1 repeated matches)

Comment: @asoundmove: Hello again :) This questin has really got me on a maximum learning curve :) ... As a result of it, I've started using `awk` for the first time, and now that you've got yours running in "advanced" sed mode, I've followed suit and finally got myself into gear and tangled with branching in sed, and I'v even used the holding space today (as a test)... Actually I don't think it should be called "advanced"; it does just a few basic text moves and shifts and offers very limited branching; it is just cryptic.. Anyhow your script is now on par timewise with `awk` (1% slower)....BUT...

Comment: ... but, even though I a pro-sed ++, I think this particular job is beyond its limits, for anything other than one' own personal tool.. Here is the main issue sed has in this case (yours, and mine.. I managed to get sed to do the same as yours.. it also ran within 1%).. back to the main issue..(which does not apply to awk).... Bug(not fixable): Regarding a date which is valid within the scope of the log, but is not actually present in the log will, in the case of the 1st arg, cause sed to print nothing, and in the case of the 2nd arg, sed wil print everything after the first date! ... more...

Comment: Another, fixable bug: Is that it currently matches dates anywhewere in any line, including the data protion, but that's just a regex tweak.. And for anyone wanting to use it, perhaps you could comment that the args now refer to the first and last dates in range (not -1 and +1).. and finally.. my "exacting standards" are not mine. I am only the messenger of the Questioners request... The user *will* notice if it works as requested, or not.. This has been a great question for me.. I've learnt a lot :) ... and I glad to know that `sed` can match `awk` for speed, and it was actually a bit faster.

Answer (score 6):

To print everything between FOO and BAR inclusive, try:

```
$ sed -n '/FOO/,/BAR/p' file.txt
```

Comment: note: This will only print the first BAR of a series of consecutive BARS...

Comment: another note... Big problem if either of the dates aren't present in the data.. If the last date is not present, sed will keep outputting lines until it reaches EOF.

Answer (score 5):

This will do what you want...
Both Including and Excluding the parameter dates are shown.

```
# set Test args
set  2011-02-24  2011-02-26  "junk"

from="$1"
till="$2"
file="$3"

# EITHER ====                              +++++++++  
# Ouptut lines between two parameter dates INCLUDING the parameter dates
  awk -v from=$from -v till=$till '
    ($2 >= from) && ($2 <= till) { print $0 ; next }
    ($2 > till) { exit }' "$file"

# OR ========                              ---------
# Ouptut lines between two parameter dates EXCLUDING the parameter dates
  awk -v from=$from -v till=$till '
    ($2 > from) && ($2 < till) { print $0 ; next }
    ($2 >= till) { exit }' "$file"
```

---

It tests for a (sorted) date in field 2... Here is an example fo the test data

```
    98  2011-02-05 xxxx
    99  2011-02-05 xxxx
   100  2011-02-06 xxxx
   101  2011-02-06 xxxx
```

---

And here is the [test-data generator](http://paste.ubuntu.com/572877/).

Comment: I would write it (taking the first one for example) a little more simply thus:
 `awk -v from="$from" -v till="$till" '($2 >= from) { if ($2 <= till) { print } else { exit }' "$file"`

Comment: @asoundmove: Yes, that may **look** better, and it is definitely more **conventional**, but in reality, its execution time is only the duration of 1 extra `if` statement *in total* (not even 1 per line) ie. the logic flow is effectively the same, and the difference in run time would be counted in nanoseconds.... The only reason I didn't use "else" is that this is effectively my first ever `awk` script (aside from one day 4 years ago when I played with some examples)... and that is the first workable branch mechanism I found...(and as mentioned. it's just as fast).. I generly use `sed` Try `q`

Comment: I don't understand where you give the text file name and location in this method? can someone help me see through my stupidity

Answer (score 4):

If in your log file you have the dates in this format `YYYY-MM-DD`, then, to find all entries for say, 2011-02-10, you can do:

```
grep 2011-02-10 log_file
```

Now, say, if you want to find the entries for 2011-02-10 and 2011-02-11, then, again use `grep` but with multiple patterns:

```
grep -E '2011-02-10|2011-02-11' log_file
```

Comment: Good. It works "as advertised" :) ... However, `grep` will search the entire file, even if the date **range** is at the start of the file. On average this doubles the time of a search, when compared to "exit-after-last-item-in-range"... I'm only bothering to mention this because of the 8 GB file size mentioned in the question, Your grep time results are almost identical to the sed example here (1min 58sec). Here is the link to my time tests results: http://paste.ubuntu.com/573477/

Answer (score 1):

Working with this size of files is always hard.

A way forward could be to split this file into a couple small ones, 
to do this you can use the split command.

```
split -d -l 50000 ToBigFile.data file_
```

Even thou it is split up you can still work with the file like if would be one using a bash for loop

```
for f in `ls file_*`; do cat $f; done;
```

But instead of the cat you can use inverted grep to get rid of unwanted data, that is irrelevant for this. (or the kind of refinement that you need).

At this point you will just work with a lot of smaller files, and the commands the others mentioned above will work smother on a lot of smaller files.

And when you are done, you can use a second for loop to build up the new smaller file again.

```
for f in `ls file_*`; do cat $f >> NewFile.data ; done;
```

---

*Update* 
Since we start to split the data in multiple files, there is going to be a lot of work with the harddrive and that takes time. (In this question apparently 5min).

On the other hand the next steps would probably be faster.

So this method is probably pointless for simple grep, awk, sed operation, 
but if the search patterns becomes more complicated it could become faster.

Comment: Johanm, it takes awk and sed only 1 minute, on average,  to search an 8 GB log file on my computer, and on the same compuer, just the inital file splitting, takes 4min 43sec ... :)

Comment: Let's say that you could cut those awk and sed times by 50% on the smaller files. Then we still need to do more than 10 of those operation before we gain on the total time... So maybe the file split is not the best idea for a few regressions...

Comment: The awk script could (easily) be modified to output 10 different search results to 10 files..in one single pass, but that would slow the read down while actually outputing the reports... Sed could also do the same, but as I've mentioned in asoundmove's comments, sed will fail if a particular date/time has no entry in the log(eg, you are searching by the hour).. I use sed a lot and it is extremely useful, but it has its limits... Here is a sed FAQ about when to use sed vs awk.. I don't necessarily agree with all of it, but I can see what they mean...  http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq6.html

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -wlne '/^2011-02-24/ .. /^2011-02-25/ and print' log_file
```

Comment: This will only print the first log entry for 2011-02-25 though.