# Fast way to build a test file with every second listed in YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS format

Tags: bash, text-processing, performance, date

I want to create a large test file with lines containg dates listed by the second, but my method is taking inordinately long... (or at least, that's how it feels :) ... 43 minutes to create only 1051201 lines. 20.1 MB file....

I want to crate a much bigger file, with each line's date being unique..
Is there a faster way than how I've approached it?:

```
# # BEGIN CREATE TEST DATA  ============ 
# # Create some dummy data.
  file=/tmp/$USER/junk
  ((secY2 =s3600*24*365*2))
  cnt=0
  secBeg=$(date --date="2010-01-01 00:00:00" +%s)
  secEnd=$((secBeg+secY2))
  ((sec=secBeg))
  while ((sec<=secEnd)) ; do
      date -d '1970-01-01 UTC '$sec' seconds' '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' >>"$file" 
      ((sec+=1))
      ((cnt+=1))
  done
  ls -l "$file"
  echo Lines written: $cnt
# END CREATE TEST DATA  ============
```

Comment: Your requirements are very strange, why do you need a file full of timestamps? Perhaps you are ignoring the obvious solution that does not involve using the shell and a megabyte-long file of easily computable information...

Comment: It would improve a little if your script *echoed* instead of appending (`>>`). Use `./script > afile` to save the echoed data.

Comment: magabyte-long? ... I'm looking for gigabytes :) The volume of data is one of the things I want.. and ascending dates is another.. I want to test a script which searches a log by date.. and now I'm more interested in why it is so slow... I suspect that keeping it local to bash is the way to go... but that needs a date algorithm... I'll try that and see how it goes... I want to compare search methods on a large log... http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8121/how-to-cut-part-from-log-file/8264#8264

Comment: I've now tried Eelvex's suggestion, and I also directed the output to /dev/null .. and all 3 methods are within a minute of each other, at 57 minutes... and surprisingley (while...do) >"$file" was the slowest... That got me thingking.. I'm about to try Iain's answer....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I haven't made any benchmark, but I see a few potential improvements.

You open and close the file for each call to `date`. This is a waste: just put the redirection around the whole loop.

```
while …; do …; done >"$file"
```

You're making separate calls to `date` for each line. Unix is good at calling external programs quickly, but internal is still better. GNU date has a batch option: feed it dates on standard input, and it pretty-prints them. Furthermore, to enumerate a range of integers, use `seq`, it's likely to be faster than interpreting the loop in the shell.

```
seq -f @%12.0f $secBeg $secEnd | date -f - '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' >"$file"
cnt=$(($secY2 + 1))
```

Generally speaking, if your shell script is too slow, try to have the inner loop executed in a dedicated utility — here `seq` and `date`, but often `sed` or `awk`. If you can't manage that, switch to a more advanced scripting language such as Perl or Python (but the dedicated utilities are typically faster, if you fit their use cases).

Comment: Thanks Gilles... It is a good thing that we learn by our mistakes... (I've been learning a lot lately :) ... I'm certainly more aware now of the these 'internal batch options' you've mentioned...

Comment: OMG! ...500 times faster than my script ! 8.6 seconds (the seq needs some tweaking.. It's putting out scientific notation. I used brace expansion kludge, because I couldn't spot the right seq option.) ...

Comment: @fred.bear: Ah, yes, it's annoying that `seq` doesn't accept integer formats. `%12.0f` will do the trick until the year 33658. Most architectures have 52-bit floating point mantissa, so you can go up to `%15.0f` and still be able to express integers exactly.

Comment: This is what I used: `eval echo -n @{$secBeg..$secEnd}\$\'\\n\'` .... it adds a leading space to all bar the first line, but it's okay for this situation... ;)

Comment: @Gilles, youv'e introduced me to another "use the right tool for the job at hand" ... `seq` is 6 times faster (for list generaton aspect) than is `echo {1..n}`.... `seq`'s  only limit seems to be it's 'float' cap (which, as you've mentioned, is "adequate" :)....Aside from speed, `echo {1..n}` bombs out, when my 3.2 GB RAM-gauge maxes out, with a tally of a trivial 15 million items... ( I need 429 million ) ... I've asked a seperate question about brace expansion limits: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8326/what-governs-the-limits-of-shell-brace-expansion

Comment: For those interested, here is how it panned out using Gilles' method... For the finished product of 429520320 (429 million) lines; ie. 13.6 years of dates (one second per line):... The `seq` expansion alone (to /dev/null) takes 14 minutes... The entire job of creating an 8 GB file took 45 minutes.

Comment: "I haven't made any benchmark".  See my answer for benchmarks.

Answer (score 4):

We know it's slow from running:

```
$ time ./junk.sh
Lines written: 14401
./junk.sh  2.27s user 3.31s system 21% cpu 25.798 total
```

(and that's a version that only prints 4 hours, not 2 years.)

To get a better understanding of where `bash` is spending its time, we can use `strace -c`.

```
$ strace -c ./junk.sh
Lines written: 14401
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 79.01    0.128906           4     28806     14403 waitpid
 17.92    0.029241           2     14403           clone
  2.45    0.003999           0    158448           rt_sigprocmask
  0.33    0.000532           0     28815           rt_sigaction
  0.29    0.000479           0     14403           sigreturn
```

So we can see that the top two calls are `waitpid` and `clone`.  They don't take up much time on their own (only 0.128906 seconds and 0.029241 seconds), but we can see they are being called a lot, so we are suspecting the problem is the fact we are having to start a separate `date` command to echo each number.

So then I did some searching, and found out you can compile `bash` with `gprof` support by doing:

```
$ ./configure --enable-profiling --without-bash-malloc
$ make
```

Now using that:

```
$ ./bash-gprof junk.sh
Lines written: 14401
$ gprof ./bash-gprof gmon.out

Each sample counts as 0.01 seconds.
  %   cumulative   self              self     total           
 time   seconds   seconds    calls   s/call   s/call  name    
  8.05      0.28     0.28    14403     0.00     0.00  make_child
  6.61      0.51     0.23                             __gconv_transform_utf8_internal
  5.75      0.71     0.20                             fork
  5.75      0.91     0.20   259446     0.00     0.00  hash_search
  5.17      1.09     0.18   129646     0.00     0.00  dispose_words
```

So assuming the function names are meaningful, it confirms that the problem is we are making `bash` fork and call an external command repeatedly.

If we move the `>>` to the end of the `while` loop, it barely makes a dent.

```
$ time ./junk2.sh
...
./junk2.sh  2.46s user 3.18s system 22% cpu 25.659 total
```

But Gilles' answer finds a way to only run `date` once, and not surprisingly, it's **much** faster:

```
$ time ./bash-gprof junk3.sh
Lines written: 14401
./bash-gprof junk3.sh  0.10s user 0.16s system 96% cpu 0.264 total

$ strace -c ./bash-gprof junk3.sh
Lines written: 14401
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 97.63    0.039538        5648         7         3 waitpid
  2.37    0.000961          37        26           writev
  0.00    0.000000           0         9           read
  ...
  0.00    0.000000           0         4           clone


$ gprof ./bash-gprof gmon.out 
Flat profile:

Each sample counts as 0.01 seconds.
 no time accumulated

  %   cumulative   self              self     total           
 time   seconds   seconds    calls  Ts/call  Ts/call  name    
  0.00      0.00     0.00     1162     0.00     0.00  xmalloc
  0.00      0.00     0.00      782     0.00     0.00  mbschr
  0.00      0.00     0.00      373     0.00     0.00  shell_getc
```

7 `waitpids` and 4 `clones` compared to 28806 and 14403 in the original!

So the moral is: If you have to call an external command inside a loop that is repeated many times, you either need to find a way to move it out of the loop, or switch to a programming language that doesn't have to call an external command to do the work.

---

As requested, a test based on Iain's method (modified to use same variable names and looping):

```
#!/bin/bash
datein=junk.$$.datein
file=junk.$$
((secY2=3600*4))
cnt=0
secBeg=$(date --date="2010-01-01 00:00:00" +%s)
secEnd=$((secBeg+secY2))
((sec=secBeg))
while ((sec<=secEnd)) ; do
  echo @$sec >>"$datein"
  ((sec+=1))
  ((cnt+=1))
done
date --file="$datein" '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' >>"$file"
ls -l "$file"
rm "$datein"
echo Lines written: $cnt
```

Results:

```
$ time ./bash-gprof ./junk4.sh 
Lines written: 14401
./bash-gprof ./junk4.sh  0.92s user 0.20s system 94% cpu 1.182 total

$ strace -c ./junk4.sh
Lines written: 14401
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 91.71    0.116007       14501         8         4 waitpid
  3.70    0.004684           0     14402           write
  1.54    0.001944           0     28813           close
  1.35    0.001707           0     72008         1 fcntl64
  0.88    0.001109           0     43253           rt_sigprocmask
  0.45    0.000566           0     28803           dup2
  0.36    0.000452           0     14410           open

$ gprof ./bash-gprof gmon.out 
Flat profile:

Each sample counts as 0.01 seconds.
  %   cumulative   self              self     total           
 time   seconds   seconds    calls  ms/call  ms/call  name    
 22.06      0.15     0.15                             __gconv_transform_utf8_internal
 16.18      0.26     0.11                             mbrtowc
  7.35      0.31     0.05                             _int_malloc
  5.88      0.35     0.04                             __profile_frequency
  4.41      0.38     0.03   345659     0.00     0.00  readtok
  4.41      0.41     0.03                             _int_free
  2.94      0.43     0.02   230661     0.00     0.00  hash_search
  2.94      0.45     0.02    28809     0.00     0.00  stupidly_hack_special_variables
  1.47      0.46     0.01   187241     0.00     0.00  cprintf
  1.47      0.47     0.01   115232     0.00     0.00  do_redirections
```

So `close` and `open` are showing up.

Now Eelvex's observation about `>>` per line versus `>` around the `while` loop starts to make a difference.

Let's factor it out...

```
#!/bin/bash
datein=junk.$$.datein
file=junk.$$
((secY2=3600*4))
cnt=0
secBeg=$(date --date="2010-01-01 00:00:00" +%s)
secEnd=$((secBeg+secY2))
for ((sec=secBeg; sec<=secEnd; sec=sec+1)) ; do
  echo @$sec
  ((cnt+=1))
done >"$datein"
date --file="$datein" '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' >>"$file"
ls -l "$file"
rm "$datein"
echo Lines written: $cnt

$ time ./junk6.sh
Lines written: 14401
./junk6.sh  0.58s user 0.14s system 95% cpu 0.747 total

$ strace -c junk6.sh
Lines written: 14401
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 97.41    0.092263       11533         8         4 waitpid
  2.06    0.001949           0     43252           rt_sigprocmask
  0.53    0.000506           0     14402           write
  0.00    0.000000           0        13           read
  0.00    0.000000           0        10           open
  0.00    0.000000           0        13           close
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           execve

$ gprof ./bash-gprof gmon.out
Flat profile:

Each sample counts as 0.01 seconds.
  %   cumulative   self              self     total           
 time   seconds   seconds    calls  ms/call  ms/call  name    
 10.00      0.05     0.05    72025     0.00     0.00  expand_word_internal
 10.00      0.10     0.05                             __gconv_transform_utf8_internal
  8.00      0.14     0.04                             __profile_frequency
  8.00      0.18     0.04                             _int_malloc
  4.00      0.20     0.02  1355024     0.00     0.00  xmalloc
  4.00      0.22     0.02   303217     0.00     0.00  mbschr
```

Which is also much, **much** faster than the original script, but slightly slower that Gilles'.

Comment: @Mikel: Nice. Could you also try Iain's answer (single call to `date`, but enumeration in the shell rather than `seq`)? What are your system characteristics (in particular the kernel and filesystem can strongly impact the costs of forking and file accesses)?

Comment: Sure.  It's Ubuntu 10.10 32-bit with Linux 2.6.35-25-generic, ext4 /tmp, on a dual-core AMD Athlon X2 system.

Comment: Great analysis - Is the  while loop faster than the for loop ?

Comment: @Iain: Average of 5 runs, lowest and highest removed: for loop=0.752666 sec, while loop=0.751333 sec.  So I don't think there's a difference.

Comment: Thanks thats interesting to know. Out of curiosity I knocked up a simple c program to generate the seconds which are piped straight into `date -f - ...`  and get a logfile of size 1261440020 in 6m48 which is about 10.8Gb/Hr on my single core Ubuntu VM.

Comment: @Iain: C is faster than shell?  Well I never! :->

Answer (score 3):

This script generates a 10 million line 201Mb file in 7m50.0s on a VM I have handy. That's about 1.5Gb/hr.

```
#!/bin/bash
Tstart=$(date +%s)
let Tend=$Tstart+100000000

[ -e datein.txt ] && rm datein.txt
[ -e logfile.log ] && rm logfile.log

for (( Tloop=Tstart; Tloop <=Tend; Tloop++ ))
do
    echo @$Tloop >> datein.txt
done

date --file=datein.txt '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' >>logfile.log
```

Comment: @Iain: Excellent, Thanks... It's obvious and I couldn't see it, even though I've been thinking about it lately... ie. how system calls beyond bash's own environment (eg. to `date`) incurr a serious (dare I say severe) overhead... My script issues a system call for each and every line in the log.. Whereas, in your case, you are making a total of 2 system calls to 'date'; 1 for the feeder, and 1 for the log itself.. QED!.. The 57 minutes has been reduced to 1 min...  (This must rate as a classic example of why to not make external calls in a willy-nilly manner... I plead ignorance :)

Comment: @Iain: I've been amazed by your script, and 57 times faster is very good, but Gilles has come up with a script that means he has to get the 'best' answer ... Gille's script has pared it down to 8.6 seconds! (for the number of lines in **my example**) ...approximately 500 times faster than my script !

Comment: @Iain: I've been puzzling all day (well, not all day, but on and off) over why there is such a time difference  difference beteween your method and Gilles'...  I just spotted it (maybe??)... Although you make only 2 calls to `date`, you make 100000000 (or whatever) appends to file datein.txt. whereas Gilles' method uses 1 call to `seq` and then the shell just pipes it's output stream to `date`.... Wow! I need a coffee! but what a great lesson...

Comment: @fred.bear:  Yes, using the method I proposed generating the input file takes a long time. The date command takes relatively little time.

Comment: PS.. and `date` also has to read that file 100000000 times(?) .. whatever the exact details are, It seems that using the shell directly is the take-home message ..  .. I didn't get my edit done in time (again ;)

Comment: Reading the file is quite cheap, it's the opens/write/close that is expensive.