# Fastest way to create a file of 1MM unique nanosecond timestamps

Tags: bash

My current (slow) example is this:

```
for i in {1..1000000}; do echo "$(date +%s)$(date +%N)"; done > 1m-example.txt
```

Hopefully there's a better way.  It's crazy slow.

Comment: See this Q&A: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8273/fast-way-to-build-a-test-file-with-every-second-listed-in-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss-fo

Comment: besides slowness, the two calls to `date` will result in time parts that don't even belong together.  But does it have to be shell script?

Comment: Do you need these to be interpretable as Unix timestamps or will @Graeme's answer suffice?

Comment: They don't have to be parsable as Unix timestamps.  I figured my lame implementation wouldn't be too bad, but darn it was slow.

Answer (score 2):

If it is just arbitrary timestamps, then there is no real need for `date` (they are just numbers, right?). How about something like:

```
printf '1393548962358%s\n' {000000..999999} >1m-example.txt
```

If there is no issue with them being consecutive. Another idea, closer to your original, is to use the following:

```
yes now | head -n 1MB | date -f - +%s%N >1m-example.txt
```

This will leave some space between numbers which varies with the natural entropy of the system. Something to watch out for here is hardware/implementation dependence as full nanosecond timestamps may not be supported, eg you may just have millisecond or even second accuracy. In this case you would have repeating numbers with zeros at the end with would likely repeat. Works ok for me though!

#### Update

As a side note, if you are trying to create timestamps to be *read* by `date`, you need the prepend an `@` so that `date` will interpret them as timestamps and not as formatted dates/times. Also, a decimal point is required since `date` only takes timestamps in seconds (and not nanoseconds). See the following example (and comments below):

```
printf '@1393548962.358%s\n' {000000..000005} | date -f - '+%F %T.%N'
```

Comment: These are just numbers, aren't they?

Comment: @slm, exactly my point!

Comment: This won't work, time measurements are in base 60, so many of your numbers won't actually be interpretable as timestamps. Specifically, your answer will only create 36524 valid timestamps and 963476 invalid ones. Shame though, that's _fast_!

Comment: @terdon a Unix timestamp is the *number of seconds* since midnight 01/01/1970. This is what `date +%s`produces. The rest is just fractions of seconds. There is no base 60, your thinking of a formatted time.

Comment: Facepalm! I am indeed, fair point. Nevertheless, your `printf` approach only produces 36524 valid timestamps, I counted! I just gave an idiotic, wrong explanation.

Comment: @terdon how so? What makes them invalid?

Comment: I'm not sure, but they are. Try this: `printf '%s\n' 139354896235{0000001..1000000} | date -f -  | head`

Comment: @terdon your have to prepend an `@` for date to interpret as timestamps or else it will try to extract a date/time format (and somehow manages to do so 36524 times). Even then it only interprets seconds, so you also need a decimal point. Also an output format that includes the nanoseconds or all the dates/times will be the same - `printf '@1393548962.358%s\n' {000001..999999} | date -f - '+%F %T.%N' | less`

Comment: Ah yes, I had used the `@`, it was the decimal point I'd missed. May as well add that to your A.

Answer (score 1):

Below are 2 methods. The 2nd method that uses `seq` + `date` to mimic what your question was asking for. However this method using `/dev/urandom` and `fold` will produce random numeric strings that are whatever length you want.

#### Method #1. Using /dev/urandom + fold

You can use a command like this to generate a random string that is fixed length.

```
$ tr -dc '0-9' </dev/urandom | fold -w 18 | head -n 1MB >1m-example.txt
```

Resulting in this type of output:

```
$ head -5 1m-example.txt
405295373332357365
317790052799018265
512803158528955068
838448126037265342
014951048334094344
```

Time:

```
real    0m30.261s
user    0m1.700s
sys     0m29.976s
```

#### Method #2. Using seq + date

Something like this will generate batch data that can then be piped to `date` in a single call:

```
$ seq -f @%12.0f 1 1000000 | date -f - '+%s%N' > 1m-example.txt
```

#### What's going on?

```
$ seq -f @%12.0f 1 1000000 | head -5
@           1
@           2
@           3
@           4
@           5
```

Resulting this type of output:

```
$ seq -f @%12.0f 1 1000000 | head -5 | date -f - '+%s%N'
1000000000
2000000000
3000000000
4000000000
5000000000
```

Time:

```
real    0m8.647s
user    0m3.547s
sys     0m5.971s
```

But this seems completely unnecessary, since you appear to just want 1MM rows of random data of a particular format/type. In that case I would do something like [@Graeme](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/117360/7453) solution using `printf` with the shell's brace expansion instead.

Comment: Nice, was wondering how to do it with `unrandom`. Few points though, `1M` with head is 1024*1024, 1MB is 1000000. Also the maximum timestamp for many systems is 2,147,483,647 (INT32_MAX). 18 digits will give nanoseconds up to around 09/2001, more digits requires 64 bit timestamps. Finally, method 1 does not guarantee unique numbers, just a very small probability of repeats.

Comment: @Graeme - (1) good catch on the 1M, did that off the cuff, you're correct 1MB is the proper argument. (2) In looking at the original example noted that his output was returning up to 20 digits, so I reflected that in my implementation, it's obviously configurable so the OP can change to suite his needs. (3) correct there is a very very very very small probability that the numbers will repeat. If the OP ever comes back I might calculate the prob. otherwise it isn't worth worrying about, IMO.